# PHP not creating array correctly from XML?

Tags: php, xml, xmldom

I am really confused with why this is happening have spent (quite a lot of time, more than I would like to admit). Basically when it gets to Date it does not add the date to the array whereas Time is absolutely fine.

**XML Code Example**

```
<xml>
<Route id="1">
    <itdDateTime>
        <itdDate day="28" month="10" year="2012" weekday="-1"/>
        <itdTime hour="12" minute="53"/>
    </itdDateTime>
</Route>
<Route id="2">
    <itdDateTime>
        <itdDate day="3" month="12" year="2012" weekday="-1"/>
        <itdTime hour="8" minute="14"/>
    </itdDateTime>
</Route>
<Route id="3">
    <itdDateTime>
        <itdDate day="3" month="12" year="2012" weekday="-1"/>
        <itdTime hour="9" minute="16"/>
    </itdDateTime>
</Route>
```

**PHP Code Example**

```
foreach($route->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName == 'itdDateTime') {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
            $dateAttr = $child->attributes;
            $x[$i]['leave'] = array();
            $x[$i]['leave']['date'] = array();
            $x[$i]['leave']['time'] = array();
            foreach ($dateAttr as $index=>$attr) {
                $x[$i][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;             
                if ($index == 'minute' || $index == 'hour') {
                    $x[$i]['leave']['time'][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
                } else {
                    $x[$i]['leave']['date'][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Array example**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [active] => 1
            [delete] => 0
            [changes] => 2
            [distance] => 966
            [alternative] => 0
            [publicDuration] => 01:19
            [individualDuration] => 00:22
            [print] => 0
            [routeIndex] => 1
            [hasFrequency] => 1
            [routeTripIndex] => 1
            [cTime] => 20121028113640847
            [searchMode] => 1
            [vehicleTime] => 53
            [method] => itp
            [selected] => 1
            [leave] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [time] => Array
                        (
                            [hour] => 12
                            [minute] => 53
                        )

                )

            [day] => 28
            [month] => 10
            [year] => 2012
            [weekday] => 1
            [hour] => 12
            [minute] => 53
        )
```

**Problem**

So basically the issue is that the date (day, month, weekday) should be entered into 
[leave][date] .. (example) [leave][date][day]

Even having no IF Statement, and entering it into [leave] array only doesnt work for example

```
$x[$i]['leave'][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
```

So Im basically unsure and dont understand why it will show in the first array (such as next to Leave as per the example)

```
$x[$i][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
```

Any advice or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you need that in an array at all? why cant you just use the DOM Structure?

Comment: @Gordon it's OK, because it's be better to parse DOM only once and cache the array, then parse XML every time.

Comment: well Im wanting to turn the XML into JSON so I am first stripping the XMl out (the xml file itself is massive and has a lot of extra information i dont need.

Comment: @Hast just that the actual *parsing* into a DOM Tree happens only once when you load the XML, so that argument is kinda moot. Transforming the DOM Tree into a multi-dimensional array is just transforming the in-memory representation of the XML from one data structure to another. It's pointless.

Comment: @Gordon why? A large XML file could slow an execution. Should we parse it every time? I don't think so.

Comment: @NickWhite you sure about xml data is valid and you don't miss something in it's structure? Did you try var_dump() for every iteration?

Comment: @Hast it's not "parsed every time" but only **once** when you call `loadXML`

Comment: @Hast yes I am sure the other bits of the XML data structure I do not need to have for what I am attempting to do for this site

Comment: @Gordon some caching systems doesn't natively support object caching. I'm sure there are some problems in memcached with it. Moreover, if you are using such library as SimpleXML, you have to use typecast for every value from the DOM.

Comment: @Hast no offense but these "arguments" are nonsense. There is nothing in the question asking for memcached, so even if there was any problems it's completely irrelevant here. And the OP is not using SimpleXML, so it's irrelevant as well. The OP gave a valid reason though by asking to transform the XML into JSON. Could still do that with an XSLT though.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
    ...
    $x[$i]['leave'] = array();
    $x[$i]['leave']['date'] = array();
    $x[$i]['leave']['time'] = array();
    ...
}
```

This loop runs twice, for `itdDate` and `itdTime`, and as you can see on second iteration it is overwriting previously filled array with empty one.

You should check if these arrays does not exist before overwriting them, or better move their definition before looping through `itdDateTime` child nodes:

```
if ($node->nodeName == 'itdDateTime') {
    $x[$i]['leave'] = array();
    $x[$i]['leave']['date'] = array();
    $x[$i]['leave']['time'] = array();
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $dateAttr = $child->attributes;
        foreach ($dateAttr as $index=>$attr) {
            $x[$i][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;             
            if ($index == 'minute' || $index == 'hour') {
                $x[$i]['leave']['time'][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
            } else {
                $x[$i]['leave']['date'][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see but does this not get sorted with the IF Statement? or am I missing something with that then

Comment: It doesn't run twice. As I can see, there is only one $i = 0. Even so, time would been either overwritten in that case.

Comment: @NickWhite you don't have if statement around it, add `if(!isset($x[$i]['leave'])){ }` around these array definitions and it will solve your problem